# $\int\limits_0^{\pi}\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\sin(nx)}{n^2}dx=2\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(2n-1)^3}$

Tags: uniform-convergence

I am stuck with this simple problem. I am obviously making a stupid mistake somewhere, could anybody help me out? Need to show that:

$$\int_0^{\pi}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\sin(nx)}{n^2}dx=2\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(2n-1)^3}$$

Since the sequence is uniformly convergent, I put the integral sign after the sum. but then I get

$$\int_0^{\pi}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\sin(nx)}{n^2}dx=2\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^3}$$

Since
$$\int_0^{\pi}\frac{\sin(nx)}{n^2}dx=\frac{-\cos(nx)}{n^3}\Bigg|_0^{\pi}=\frac{2}{n^3}$$

Where is the mistake? Thanks!

Comment: yes, definitely. fixed that :)

Comment: What is $\cos(n\pi)$ again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure that the integral is *always* $2/n$?  What happens when $n$ is even?